# How can I set the android channel notification from code in firebase cloud function?

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having a few issues trying to customize how my notifications appear on my Android Unity application:

I send the notifications using cloud functions, the app is subscribed to a topic, and the backend (in that case the cloud function) listens to the real-time database in order to send a message to all users subscribed to that topic.
The main issue that it seems that by default all sent notifications are assigned to the Miscellaneous channel, which has almost all its properties disabled: floating animations, sound etc.

I saw that you can set the notification channel in the firebase console and I was wondering if there's something similar in cloud functions because I didn't find anything...
[image: Channel id image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: It seems that you can assign the category that you want to relate the message:

```
                    const message = {
                    android:{
                        notification:{
                            title: 'Game started!',
                            body: 'Game '+ salaName +' has started!',
                            channel_id: "notification.category.default",
                        }
                    },
                    topic: "topicName"
                };
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#androidfcmoptions